# How can I make this LINQ query of an Enumerable DataTable of GTFS data faster?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq, gtfs

I'm working with the GTFS data for the New York City MTA subway system. I need to find the stop times for each route at a specific stop. To do that, I get the stop times from a StopTimes DataTable that I have, for a specific stop_id. I only want stop times between now and the next 2 hours.

Then, I need to lookup the trip for each stop time, using the trip_id value. From that trip, I have to lookup the route, using the route_id value, in order to get the route name or number for the stop time.

Here are the counts for each DataTable: StopTimes(522712), Trips(19092), Routes(27).

Right now, this takes anywhere from 20 seconds to 40 seconds to execute. How can I speed this up? Any and all suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

```
foreach (var r in StopTimes.OrderBy(z => z.Field<DateTime>("departure_time").TimeOfDay)
                           .Where(z => z.Field<string>("stop_id") == stopID &&
                                  z["departure_time"].ToString() != "" &&
                                  z.Field<DateTime>("departure_time").TimeOfDay >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-5).TimeOfDay &&
                                  z.Field<DateTime>("departure_time").TimeOfDay <= DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-5).AddHours(2).TimeOfDay))
        {
            var trip = (from z in Trips
                        where z.Field<string>("trip_id") == r.Field<string>("trip_id") &&
                              z["route_id"].ToString() != ""
                        select z).Single();

            var route = (from z in Routes
                         where z.Field<string>("route_id") == trip.Field<string>("route_id")
                         select z).Single();

            // do stuff (not time-consuming)
        }
```

Comment: I would put the order by after your where clause see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var tod0 = now.AddHours(-5).TimeOfDay;
var tod1 = now.AddHours(-5).AddHours(2).TimeOfDay;

var sts =
    from st in StopTimes
    let StopID = st.Field<string>("stop_id")
    where StopID == stopID
    where st["departure_time"].ToString() != ""
    let DepartureTime = st.Field<DateTime>("departure_time").TimeOfDay
    where DepartureTime >= tod0
    where DepartureTime >= tod1
    let TripID = st.Field<string>("trip_id")
    select new
    {
        StopID,
        TripID,
        DepartureTime,
    };
```

Note that there is no `orderby` in this query and that we're returning an anonymous type. For your "do stuff (not time-consuming)" code to run you may need to add some more properties.

The same approach happens for `Trips` & `Routes`.

```
var ts =
    from t in Trips
    where t["route_id"].ToString() != ""
    let TripID = t.Field<string>("trip_id")
    let RouteID = t.Field<string>("route_id")
    select new
    {
        TripID,
        RouteID,
    };

var rs =
    from r in Routes
    let RouteID = r.Field<string>("route_id")
    select new
    {
        RouteID,
    };
```

Since you're getting a single record for each look up then using `ToDictionary(...)` is a good choice to use.

```
var tripLookup = ts.ToDictionary(t => t.TripID);
var routeLookup = rs.ToDictionary(r => r.RouteID);
```

Now your query looks like this:

```
var query = from StopTime in sts.ToArray()
            let Trip = tripLookup[StopTime.TripID]
            let Route = routeLookup[Trip.RouteID]
            orderby StopTime.DepartureTime
            select new
            {
                StopTime,
                Trip,
                Route,
            };
```

Notice that I've used `.ToArray()` and I've put the `orderby` right at the end.

And you run your code like this:

```
foreach (var q in query)
{
    // do stuff (not time-consuming)
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a `Dictionary<int, Trip>` from Trips where the key is the `trip_id`, and a `Dictionary<int, Route`> from `Routes` where the key is `route_id`. your code is iterating over the 19092 items in `Trips` once for every one of the items in the filtered `IEnumerable<StopTime>`. Same deal for `Routes`, but at least there are only 27 items in there.

Edit:

actually looking at it more closely, the first dictionary would be `Dictionary<int, int>` where the value is the `route_id`. And given the one to one relationship between `trip_id` and `route_id` you could just build a `Dictionary<trip_id, Route>` and do one lookup.

Answer (score -1):

It helps to understand deferred query execution so you can make case by case decisions on how to optimize your runtime. Here is a good blog post that can get you started: http://ox.no/posts/linq-vs-loop-a-performance-test